# ofstream overwriting stack variables

Tags: c++, netbeans, g++

I'm working on a "threadpool" program for operating systems class. Essentially, files are extracted from a tar file and written to the disk, using a pool of 5 threads. Here's my thread code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

vector<Header*> headers;
vector<string> fileBlocks;
void* writeExtractedFiles(void* args)
{
    bool hasFilesLeft = true;
    ofstream outputFile;
    while(hasFilesLeft)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if(headers.size() != 0)
        {
            Header* hdr = headers.back();
            headers.pop_back();
            string fileBytes = fileBlocks.back();
            fileBlocks.pop_back();
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

            outputFile.open(hdr->fileName.c_str(), ios::app);
            outputFile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0,0);
            fileBytes = fileBytes.substr(0, hdr->fileSize);
            outputFile.put('0');
            outputFile.close();
            // This is a dummy object to check if the values are corrupted
            Header* test0 = headers.back();
            cout << "GRAWWR!";
            //chown(hdr->fileName.c_str(), hdr->userId, hdr->groupId);
            //chmod(hdr->fileName.c_str(), hdr->fileMode);
        }
        else
        {
            // We're done!
            hasFilesLeft = false;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note* As of right now, I'm only testing it with a single thread. Obviously accessing the `headers` vector outside of my mutex would be counterproductive with multiple threads.

Problem is, the values for `test0` are all messed up, super high numbers and nonsense for `fileName`. It seems like I'm overwriting my stack variables for some reason. When I comment out `outputFile.close();` then my variable values aren't changed, but when I keep it, whether I actually write things to the file or not, things get wonky. I know there must be something I'm missing. I've tried getting rid of the buffer altogether, writing the file in a different place, anything I could think of. Any suggestions?

(I'm testing it on a Windows machine but it's being made for Linux)

Comment: First, the blatantly obvious. You're accessing `headers` outside of a latch with the very item you say is "messed up". Any reason in particular you're doing that?

Comment: you have an unlock before opening the file, is that right?

Comment: @Zelldon I think that part is fine. Both the header and the file info are popped from their respective queues before the unlock. But the line immediately *after* the file close is the disheartening one. That is done entirely unprotected.

Comment: ok allright thanks for answer... yes i'm agree, that make sense

Comment: @WhozCraig - This particular line repeated outside mutex - Header* test0 = headers.back(); -  does not make any sense to me either. ReimTime - What is "tested" here?

Comment: @SChepurin - The `test0` line is simply for debugging purposes, so I can see what the last item in the vector is. I realize it's outside the mutex, but I'm testing it with simply one thread, so in theory it shouldn't mess anything up.